# php - strip path from url - no built in function?

Tags: php

Given a URL:

```
http://mysite.com/this-is/the/path
```

I just want the scheme and the host I.e. `http://mysite.com/`

Currently I am using `parse_url` and then building it back up like so:

```
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
$newUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . "://" . $urlParts['host'] . "/";
```

Is there no PHP function that can strip the path off?

Comment: Not that I know of, and arguably, there shouldn't be - seeing as 2 lines of code seem to be doing the job? The basic set of PHP's functions is enough of a bloated mess already...

Answer (score 6):

Not that I am aware of. This is a good example of a time where you may consider writing your own public function.

```
public function stripUrlPath($url){
    $urlParts = parse_url($url);
    $newUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . "://" . $urlParts['host'] . "/";
    return $newUrl;
}
```

Then use it throughout your code:

```
$newUrl = stripUrlPath($oldUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
$url = 'http://mysite.com/this-is/the/path';
$pattern = '~^(.*?//.*?)/.*~';
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // http://mysite.com
```

However, I would use `parse_url()` and rebuild the string as you currently doing.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
  echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
?>
```

Comment: -1: How about HTTPS? Also, the question is about an arbitrary url and not the current query.

Comment: maybe he doesn't care for it

Comment: It's good to write robust code that does not make unnecessary assumptions like this. You could easily lead yourself into a hidden bug trying to use such a function half a year later.

Comment: some asking don't use built in functions.. so i try to help, and he also have a solution in 2 lines above...

Comment: No offence intended. I'm not negating your will to help - I just feel that the answer could be improved. Stackoverflow is a place for all of us to learn.